# How to get string uri from HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#

I have a method that downloads file while keeping it's original name/extension:

```
public void downloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
    {
        _fileHasher = new HashFile(_controlsRef);

        using (var downloadClient = new WebClient())
        {
            downloadClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            downloadClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            string contentDisposition = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"];
            const string contentFileNamePortion = "filename=";
            Int32 fileNameStartIndex = contentDisposition.IndexOf(contentFileNamePortion, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) + contentFileNamePortion.Length;
            Int32 originalFileNameLength = contentDisposition.Length - fileNameStartIndex;
            string originalFileName = contentDisposition.Substring(fileNameStartIndex, originalFileNameLength);

            Uri URL = new Uri(urlAddress);
            location += "\\" + originalFileName;
            this._location = location;
            _downloadStopWatch.Start();
            try
            {
                downloadClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }                                  
    }
```

Then I looked up a method that downloads the file only if the file on the  hard drive is older:

```
public void DownloadAndReplace(FileSystemInfo sourceFile)
    {
        var requestFile = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("");
        requestFile.Method = "HEAD";
        var responseFile = (HttpWebResponse)requestFile.GetResponse();

        if (responseFile.LastModified > sourceFile.LastWriteTime)
        {
           // downloadFile(Here's the problem);
        }
    }
```

My question, how would I properly call the downloadFile method from DownloadAndReplace method?

Comment: I fail to see how that answers my question, also that's asp which I don't use.

Comment: please change your title to correctly reflect your requirement.  The closer the title is to the actual problem, the more likely others will find the solutions useful for their problems.  Your problem is not strictly about the actual filename, but more about the function call process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

[WebRequest.RequestUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.requesturi%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   - When overridden in a descendant class, gets the URI of the Internet resource associated with the request.

or [HttpWebResponse.ResponseUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.responseuri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: do you suggest     string requestedFile = requestFile.RequestUri.ToString(); string source = sourceFile.FullName.ToString(); and then call downloadFile(requestedFile,source); ? Am i getting this right?

Comment: @Januszoff - think you want url addrss than this line is ok  requestedFile = requestFile.RequestUri.ToString(); ..second line with give you name of file